# Finding the minimum amount of data needed to achieve a certain prediction accuracy

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, sample-size

I'm using people's past performance (e.g., GPA) to predict (with linear regression) their future performance and I want to achieve a certain level of prediction accuracy (e.g., 80%). I have data from the past 48 months and I need to find out the minimum amount of data needed to achieve this prediction accuracy.
I.e., I want to determine whether people's GPA from the past 48 months is needed to predict their future GPA with 80% accuracy or GPA from just the past 3 months is enough to achieve this accuracy level.

What would be the best way to calculate this in R?

I'm still fairly new to this so my apologies if my question is too vague.

Comment: This is really dependent on the particular sample that you use to fit your model. There’s not a magic threshold unless you make some (often inappropriate) assumptions about the distribution of the data.

Comment: If you're predicting future *observations*, there might not be such a sample size even if you know the data generating process *exactly* - unless the desired threshold is larger than the process variability.